# Lua Script - Script request

Tags: lua

Can someone help me with the following script?

```
function fffFunction(nnn)

end

fffFunction("gor")
fffFunction("ggg")
fffFunction("lle")
fffFunction("trw")
fffFunction("int")
fffFunction("ctr")
fffFunction("gsv")
fffFunction("gmd")
fffFunction("kll")
```

Complete the script, and the Expected Output I want to be like this:

```
lle
ctr
kll
```

If you don't understand, feel free to comment on test input you want to try and I will run it The only functions that ran are on the 3rd, 6th, & 9th line.

EDIT:

I tried

```
function fffFunction (nnn)
    print(nnn[3]) 
    print(nnn[6]) 
    print(nnn[9])
end
```

but the expected output was just: nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil. Then I tried to do this:

```
function fffFunction (nnn)
    ff={nnn} 
    print(ff[3]) 
    print(ff[6]) 
    print(ff[9]) 
end
```

but i get some freaky numbers and letters, something like: "table: foi0239023jr", and the other functions I want to DON'T BE PRINTED.

Comment: How to be a homework? If we'll get a homework with lua, might be so cool. We have to do Pascal. I created the script, this is what I tried. IDK what to complete more to this.

Comment: Well, it's really unclear what you're trying to achieve, and you still haven't shown what you tried. Once you have shown something you tried I can undo my downvote and I will post an answer.

Comment: Schollii, I tried, I put at the function:
print(nnn[3])
print(nnn[6])
print(nnn[9])
But I got a lot of nils at output. Also I tried writing at function this:
ff={nnn}
print(ff[3])
print(ff[6])
print(ff[9])
But isn't worked, too

Comment: *What* did you try to put in fffFunction? What is the output of the other function calls (all lines except 3, 6, 9)?

Comment: How I said up, I tryied to put in fffFunction print(nnn[3]) print (nnn[6]) print(nnn[9]) , but the expected output was just: nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil. Then I tried to do this: ff={nnn} print(ff[3]) print(ff[6]) print(ff[9]) but i get some freaky numbers and letters, something like: "table: foi0239023jr", and the other functions I want to DON'T BE PRINTED

Comment: Now you are talking. Only, must put in your question, not in comment. I have done that for you. I will post an answer, hth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this is what you want:

```
data={}
function fffFunction(nnn)
  table.insert(data,nnn)
end
function output()
  for i=1,#data do
    if (i==3 or i==6 or i==9) then
      print(data[i])
    end
  end
end

fffFunction("gor")
fffFunction("ggg")
fffFunction("lle")
fffFunction("trw")
fffFunction("int")
fffFunction("ctr")
fffFunction("gsv")
fffFunction("gmd")
fffFunction("kll")
output()
```

Answer (score 0):

please take a look in [coroutine](http://www.lua.org/pil/9.1.html) to better understand the code.

The ideia is keeping track of index between function calls, so, create a coroutine!

```
co_counter = coroutine.create(function ()                                                                                                                                                                      
    local i = 0 
    while true do
        i = i + 1 
        coroutine.yield(i)
    end 
end)

function fffFunction(nnn)
    local _, count = coroutine.resume(co_counter)
    if count % 3 == 0 then
        print (nnn)
    end 
end 

fffFunction("gor")
fffFunction("ggg")
fffFunction("lle")
fffFunction("trw")
fffFunction("int")
fffFunction("ctr")
fffFunction("gsv")
fffFunction("gmd")
fffFunction("kll")
```

Comment: It works here.. lua 5.2 :)  [edit: index multiple of tree will print the parameter... the index is what yield return, the second value of coroutine.resume]

Comment: how are you trying to execute it? which lua version are you using? I've created a test.lua with this code and run it with 'lua test.lua'... version 5.2

Comment: I don't know, I use a Lua Interface of a game named Transformice.

Comment: I don't know it, sorry. Edit your post with this information to other users be able to help you then...

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function 9 times, each time with a different string, so nnn is a different string at each call to fffFunction. Strings do not support the subscript [] operation. In your first try, the function will print 3 nils (on separate lines) every time it is called. In your second attempt, you created a table of one element, the string. Then ff[3] fetches the 3rd element of table, which is nil since there is none. You probably did print(ff) when you got the "table: weird chars" output.

The following will produce the desired output you list if you call it in the same order as you list:

```
function fffFunction(nnn)
    if nnn == "lle" or nnn == "ctr" or nnn == "kll" then
        print(nnn)
    end
end
```

Comment: If is possible, without that if. I want to be printed another thing if I'll change the functions. To make sense if i'll change functions.

Comment: This method will print all the functions, I want just the functions of lines 3,6,9. So i'll say you what I want: I want to define all those 9 functions. To be printed on the chat just the functions of the lines 3,6,9. And if i'll change the functions, the output to be different, to make sense.

Comment: I've removed the second approach since it is not what you want. But the first one still holds, and will only print lines 3, 6 and 9. However, "if i'll change the functions, the output to be different": you're going to have to say how they would be different. Maybe give more examples.

Comment: I want to say... If I change JUST THE NAME of the function, from lle, to... idk let's say IDK. The print will be IDK. With this method, the line will don't be printed, because is "if nnn == lle" and if I changed to IDK, isn't possible to be finded and printed. And I don't want the method "if not", because if I change the functions what AREN'T printed, with something different, they will be printed, too! I think you understand. Something like how do Victor Toso, but in a another method, because that method isn't working for me!

Comment: Aw, your second method was really good, do you know what I maked? I put some "--" to the other functions what aren't ran on the line 3,6 and 9

Comment: Oh, I can't use this method. Do you have a possibility?

Comment: I give up, what you explain is too hard for me to understand, have you thought of using Google translate? I hate to admit that language is a barrier here, but it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
function fffFunction(nnn)
  List = List or {print, type, type}
  table.insert(List, table.remove(List, 1))
  List[1](nnn)
end
```